# MongoDB query on array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data like below

```
> db.user.find().pretty().limit(1);
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59a7ead6d122a2332e1eb164"),
        "name" : "Jack",
        "status" : "VERIFIED",
        "attributes" : [
                {
                        "value" : "vijay jha",
                        "name" : "patient",
                        "key1" : "",
                        "key2" : "",
                        "key3" : ""
                },
                {
                        "value" : "",
                        "name" : "notes",
                        "key1" : "",
                        "key2" : "",
                        "key3" : ""
                },
                {
                        "value" : "Thomas",
                        "name" : "surgeon",
                        "key1" : "",
                        "key2" : "",
                        "key3" : ""
                }
        ]
}
```

I am trying to write query to get output like below , I am trying to use `unwind` but that is producing incorrect result

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("59a7ead6d122a2332e1eb164"),
   "name":"Jack",
   "status":"VERIFIED",
   "patient":"vijay jha",
   "notes":"",
   "surgeon":"Thomas"
}
```

Comment: @Neil Lunn : I converted the query , it is throwing error  db.user.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
  [{ "k": "_id", "v": "$_id" }],  
          { "$map": {
            "input": "$attributes",
            "in": { "k": "$$this.name", "v": "$$this.value" }
          }}
        ]
      }
    }    
  }}
])

Comment: Which error exactly? Perhaps the one telling you that `$arrayToObject` is not supported? Go back and read the nice answer again.

Comment: I am using 3.4.7 , and the error message is `"errmsg" : "'newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: null. Type of resulting value: 'null'. Input document: {_id: 59a7ead6d122a2332e1eb166}",`

Comment: It looks like we always require the `attributes` array for each document. I may have lot of documents without this array.

Comment: Then exclude them from processing. Add a `$match` and use `$exists`. Now say thankyou.